# Difference between out=... parameter and direct reassignment in NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Would the following two `np.dot` give the same result for a square array `x`?

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(4 * 4).reshape(4, 4)
np.dot(x, x.T, out=x)  # method 1
x[:] = np.dot(x, x.T)  # method 2
```

Thanks.

Why I ask:

`x += x.T` is not the same as `x += x.T.copy()`

I don't know how does the internal of np.dot work. 
Does np.dot similarly treat the out argument as a view? 
is it ok if out is one of the matrices to be multiplied?

The numpy that I am using is from anaconda, which is using mkl as a backend.

Comment: Did you try it out? You could check the id of the arrays to see if a new object was created

Comment: i worry about undefined behavior. trying is not enough. it is c behind python. it is not documented.

Comment: We don't have undefined behaviour. Seeing that the two methods are equivalent is no different than trusting that a single method has fully defined behaviour for this task

Comment: When do you expect the results to be different? Are there specific cases when it is not similar?

Comment: Why are you considering using the second case - `x[:] = ...`??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they are the same, but performance wise I see interesting results for integer arrays:

```
import perfplot

def f1(x):
    x = x.copy()
    np.dot(x, x.T, out=x)
    return x

def f2(x):
    x = x.copy()
    x[:] = np.dot(x, x.T)
    return x    

perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: np.arange(n * n).reshape(n, n),
    kernels=[f1, f2],
    labels=['out=...', 're-assignment'],
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(0, 9)],
    xlabel='N',
    equality_check=np.allclose
)
```

[image]

I've used [`perfplot`](https://github.com/nschloe/perfplot) to generate plot timings.

---

For float arrays, there is absolutely no difference.

```
perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: np.arange(n * n).reshape(n, n).astype(float),
    kernels=[f1, f2],
    labels=['out=...', 're-assignment'],
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(0, 9)],
    xlabel='N',
    equality_check=np.allclose
)
```

[image]

Comment: `x = x.copy()` memory allocation might be the main part of the timing. Or not... numpy can secretly reuse arrays it allocated.

Comment: @Rzu I don't think so, copying is not the bottleneck here, it is linear in complexity while computing the dot is O(N^3). And in any case, copying is done for both functions, so it is fair.

Comment: I worry more about if the two methods would give the same result. The 1st method should always be at least as fast as the 2nd method, if not faster.  By the way, Is your numpy using mkl as a backend?

Comment: @Rzu I add `equality_check=np.allclose` as a parameter to `perfplot.show`. If the output of the two methods was different, the function throws an AssertionError. You will see that no error is thrown, meaning it works. This was a moot point because they are identical operations differing in how the reassignment is done, that's all. And yes, my NumPy uses MKL.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both methods produce identical arrays.

```
import numpy as np

def method_1():
    x = np.arange(4 * 4).reshape(4, 4)
    np.dot(x, x.T, out=x)
    return x

def method_2():
    x = np.arange(4 * 4).reshape(4, 4)
    x[:] = np.dot(x, x.T)
    return x

array_1 = method_1()
array_2 = method_2()

print(np.array_equal(array_1, array_2))
```

gives the output:

> True

Comment: is your numpy using mkl as a backend?

Comment: Yes, my `numpy` build uses `mkl`.

Answer (score 1):

I have an older version of numpy installed (1.11.0) where method #1 produces some weird output. I understand this is not the expected behavior, and was fixed in later versions; but just in case this happens to someone else:

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.arange(4 * 4).reshape(4, 4)
>>> np.dot(x, x.T, out=x)
array([[                  14,                   94,                 1011,
                       15589],
       [              115715,          13389961335,         120510577872,
               1861218976248],
       [              182547,       21820147595568,  1728119013671256390,
         5747205779608970957],
       [              249379,       29808359122268,  7151350849816304816,
        -3559891853923251270]])
>>> np.version.version
'1.11.0'
```

As far as I can test, at least since numpy 1.14.1 the method #1 gives the expected output; as the method #2 does with both versions.

Comment: Thank you. I will ask for a numpy version >= 1.14.